# Nested If AND statement - google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, nested-if

The nested `if` statement I've tried writing keeps returning an error but I can't see where. I've seen similar threads but none with a workable syntax. I've tried with and without the `and` statement. Very simply looking at the value in a cell (C5) and returning a corresponding value-based what the number in C5 is.

```
=if(C5>84.5,1,if(and(C5<=84.5,C5>79.5,1.3,if(and(C5<=79.5,C5>74.5,1.7,if(and(C5<=74.5,C5>69.5,2,if(and(C5<=69.5,C5>64.5,2.3,if(and(C5<=64.5,C5>59.5,2.7,if(and(C5<=59.5,C5>54.5,3,if(and(C5<=54.5,C5>49.5,3.3,if(and(C5<=49.5,C5>44.5,3.7,if(and(C5<=44.5,C5>=40,4,if(C5<40,5))))))))))))))))))))
```

I expect the output to range from 1 to 5 depending on what the value in cell C5 is but I keep getting the following error

> Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments,
>   but got 1 argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You systematically forgot to close the parentheses of your `and()` functions. Try this:

```
=if(C5>84.5,1,if(and(C5<=84.5,C5>79.5),1.3,if(and(C5<=79.5,C5>74.5),1.7,if(and(C5<=74.5,C5>69.5),2,if(and(C5<=69.5,C5>64.5),2.3,if(and(C5<=64.5,C5>59.5),2.7,if(and(C5<=59.5,C5>54.5),3,if(and(C5<=54.5,C5>49.5),3.3,if(and(C5<=49.5,C5>44.5),3.7,if(and(C5<=44.5,C5>=40),4,if(C5<40,5)))))))))))
```

Comment: YEEEES! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

if you need ArrayFormula use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF( C5:C >  84.5, 1,
 IF((C5:C <= 84.5) * (C5:C >  79.5), 1.3,
 IF((C5:C <= 79.5) * (C5:C >  74.5), 1.7,
 IF((C5:C <= 74.5) * (C5:C >  69.5), 2,
 IF((C5:C <= 69.5) * (C5:C >  64.5), 2.3,
 IF((C5:C <= 64.5) * (C5:C >  59.5), 2.7,
 IF((C5:C <= 59.5) * (C5:C >  54.5), 3,
 IF((C5:C <= 54.5) * (C5:C >  49.5), 3.3,
 IF((C5:C <= 49.5) * (C5:C >  44.5), 3.7,
 IF((C5:C <= 44.5) * (C5:C >= 40),   4,
 IF( C5:C <  40, 5))))))))))))
```